# Flex-basis Auto not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 2 `articles` in a `main` that have `flex: 1 auto;` set on them, and they sit fine until I add content into them and suddenly they're both different sizes!

Nothing in them is wider than the boxes when they're at the same width, and only 2 form inputs on the left have a set width.

I can't post any code here because it's so deep and I don't want to miss anything out that could be important, so the demo is at [spendit.dpdesignz.co](http://spendit.dpdesignz.co). The boxes I'm having issues with are the login form and "Supported Banks" `articles` in the middle of the page.

I've tried setting the `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` to 0 with no luck.

This is my first time using flex, and I've worked on dozens of "fixes" over the past 5 hours with no luck, so any help/suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `flex: 0 1 50%;` (don't grow - you may want to set shrink to 0, I don't know I expect so, 50% (equal).

Comment: we all have days like that :-/